# How to determine if a superconductor is type I or II?

Tags: experimental-physics, superconductivity

What experimental measurements are available to determine whether a superconducting single crystal/polycrystalline sample is type I or II? I.e. BCS vs non-BCS?

An answer would mention the experimental procedure (including the instruments to be used) and not just a statement like "check if it has two critical fields'.

Comment: Based on the second paragraph of this post, it sounds like you're asking for a user manual for PPMS and/or SQUID measurements for checking for multiple critical fields. Is that correct?

Comment: @DanielSank I mentioned that example, because I am familiar with it. However, there might be other methods such as STM, in which case I would be happy to know the procedures .

Comment: Ok so you're asking for a complete experimental protocol for distinguishing between type I and II superconductors? Hm... I think nobody is going to be happy to write that up for you since it's undoubtedly in papers and books. Maybe trying to ask *which* technique really is a better goal here. Best of luck either way :)

Comment: That's much better as it invites useful responses from people who know how to help you. Unfortunately, I'm not such a person >.<  I would suggest adding whether or not you're working with thin films.